# Backslash in string json apiproperty

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, string, nestjs

I tried to create API and I got stuck in a problem with backslash in filepath field(?)

Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
@IsNotEmpty()
@IsString()
@ApiProperty({
    description: 'Path to .md file with data',
    type: String,
    example: "c:\Users\ivanov_ii\notes\note1.md"
})
pathToFile: string;
```

I need to get output of "example" in swagger like in apiproperty, but I get this: "pathToFile": "c:Usersivanov_ii\notes\note1.md".

I tried different ways with double backslash or quotes, but I didn't get what I needed. Output with double backslashes: "pathToFile": "c:\Users\ivanov_ii\notes\note1.md"

Comment: What is the expected string you want to have here?

Comment: You didn’t provide a [mcve], but your output suggests that when you tried to use double backslashes you forgot to double the two just after the colon.